# Checksum counterpart in .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, performance, checksum

I want to acquire a hashbytes/checksum function in C# that does exactly like SQL Server. Our SPA is posting a lot of data to our backend and I want to check for duplicates in the database before inserting. Though the best way to do this is to calculate a hash/checksum for the values I want to insert and use these in the where-clause. A unique row is identifier using a combination of columns.

```
where hashbytes('sha1', a+b+c) in (
0x40BD001563085FC35165329EA1FF5C5ECBDBBEEF
,0x5F6955D227A320C7F1F6C7DA2A6D96A851A8118F
,0x91DFDE1D6E005E422F64A59776234F1F4C80B5E4
,0x19187DC98DCE52FA4C4E8E05B341A9B77A51FD26
,0xEADC1DD8FC279583D5552700AE5D248E3FA123BD
,0xA93C168323147D1135503939396CAC628DC194C5)
```

Of course I could build a very specific where-clause to check for duplicates but thought this would be faster. I have seen a number of threads on stack about this but am struggeling on how to do this.

```
select a,b,c, CHECKSUM(a,b,c) _checkSum,hashbytes('sha1', a+b+c) _hash
from (
select '1' as a, '2' as b, '3' as c, 4 as d
union all
select '3' as a, '2' as b, '1' as c, 4 as d
union all
select '1' as a, '3' as b, '2' as c, 4 as d
union all
select '2' as a, '1' as b, '3' as c, 4 as d
union all
select '2' as a, '3' as b, '1' as c, 4 as d
union all
select '3' as a, '1' as b, '2' as c, 4 as d
) tbl
```

[image: ![Query output]

In my c# app I can have the data available in a datatable or string array. ie

```
var data = new string[] {"1", "2", "3"};
```

Question is how can I convert the **data** string array above to a checksum/hash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CHECKSUM and CHECKSUM\_AGG: What's the algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316009/checksum-and-checksum-agg-whats-the-algorithm). More important question is why you need that?

Comment: Odd thing to need, particularly client side. HASHBYTES uses standard hashing implementations.  You could always bounce the values to a server and let it do it for you.

Comment: As Alex says, you'd be better off using a standard checksum like SHA1 through HASHBYTES, for which there are readily-available .net implementations.

Comment: This is backend. Please check my edited question.

Comment: `where hashbytes('sha1', a+b+c)` over a set of rows is an extremely inefficient construction in SQL (not sargable, expensive function, concatenation), `where a = x and b = y ...` with appropriate indexes is much better. Also consider that with `HASHBYTES`  the same hash is produced for `'1' + '2' + '3'` as for `'1' + '' + '23'`

Comment: ok, I'll stick to regular where-clauses instead. Thanks for the response.