# Same Checksum in C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, checksum

I would like to retrieve the same checksum value in C# instead of using SQL code?

The goal is to retrieve the same value in c# instead of using SQL code.

Is it possible to do it?

I can't find any good answer to my question.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb6d0/3/0

Comment: Don't know the answer, but I am very curios, why do you need that?

Comment: Create temp primary key

Comment: You might try looking at `HASHBYTES` function. That one is probably more reliable and easier to implement in C#.

Comment: Almost a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316009/checksum-and-checksum-agg-whats-the-algorithm

Comment: There's a function in C# https://stackoverflow.com/a/18877860/1831734

Answer (score 2):

According to this old [article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/08/19/checksum-weakness-explained.aspx):

> The built-in CHECKUM function in SQL Server is built on a series of 4 bit left rotational xor operations

So you can try to implement this algorithm in C#.

However, that article states that this approach is not reliable from the point of collisions so probably you should not use this function at all.

I would recommend to use [HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415(v=sql.120).aspx) with any reliable algorithm i.e. MD5 instead of this CHECKSUM. At the same time C# has [built in functions for MD5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s02tk69a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin@sqlfiddle.com"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft requirement is to use HASHBYTES rather than CHECKSUM function because HASHBYTES is more efficient than CHECKSUM.

I don't know what is the algorithm used by CHECKSUM, but HASHBYTES can use these hash algorithm (MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512). You can easily do the same thing in C# with the [HashAlgorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx) Class from System.Security.Cryptography.