# What is the binary storage format for the SQL Server decimal data type?

Tags: sql-server, decimal, sqldatatypes

What is the binary storage format for the SQL Server decimal data type? I only know from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187746.aspx) how many bytes are used dependant on precision. I could use a series of `CAST (x AS BINARY(6))` and then try and infer the layout, but I'm not in the mood for that pleasure ;)

Comment: I don't think it's documented. As for the "why?", the answer is going to be the same no matter what the format is - because `CHECKSUM` is allowed, by necessity, to have collisions. E.g. `CHECKSUM(1,0)` = `CHECKSUM(0,16)`. There's nothing particularly special here.

Comment: Relevant perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316009/checksum-and-checksum-agg-whats-the-algorithm which links to http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=70832

Comment: Use `hashbytes` rather than `checksum` to lower probability of collisions.

Comment: @LesH Great find, but doesn't answer my question :(

Comment: @RhysJones it wasn't posted as an answer.

Comment: Sneaky edit there :) Best way to explain why those checksums collide is to have a look at those implementations, it's got nothing to do with how the data is stored really.

Comment: @LesH I found the checksum algorithm discussed in this [SQL Team](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/08/19/checksum-weakness-explained.aspx) posting by Peter Larsson in which the reason for collisions is explained very well, but I want to demonstrate the collisions with the decimal values 1.0, 10.0, 100.0 etc, for which I do need to know the storage format.