# How to Implement T-SQL CHECKSUM() in JavaScript for BigQuery?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, google-bigquery, hashcode

The end result I'm looking for is to implement [T-SQL CHECKSUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in BigQuery with a [JavaScript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions). I would settle for having the C/C++ source code to translate but if someone has already done this work then I'd love to use it.

Alternatively, if someone can think of a way to create an equivalent hash code between strings stored in Microsoft SQL Server compared to those in BigQuery then that would help me too.

---

- UPDATE: I've found some source code through HABO's link in the comments which is written in T-SQL to perform the same CHECKSUM but I'm having difficulty converting it to JavaScript which inherently cannot handle 64bit integers. I'm playing with some small examples and have found that the algorithm works on the low nibble of each byte *only*.
- UPDATE 2: I got really curious about replicating this algorithm and I can see some definite patterns but my brain isn't up to the task of distilling that into a reverse engineered solution. I did find that `BINARY_CHECKSUM()` and `CHECKSUM()` return different things so the work done on the former didn't help me with the latter.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316009/checksum-and-checksum-agg-whats-the-algorithm) may help you pin down the algorithm.

Comment: `CHECKSUM` is a rubbish algorithm. The best approach would be to not use it in T-SQL either, instead of reverse engineering it and spreading its deficiencies further. SQL Server has `HASHBYTES`, which gives access to more mature, common algorithms like `SHA2_256` (though even something like MD5 is better than `CHECKSUM`). Be aware that to compute an accurate hash over strings requires agreement on the encoding used, which can be tricky across languages. On the T-SQL side, the safest is hashing an `NVARCHAR`, even if your string data is `VARCHAR`, as this consistently gives you UTF-16.

Comment: Yep, all agreed but the mystery of it has me hooked now. Regardless of the algorithm's efficacy, it is out there, it's being used, and understand it would surely help _someone_ to know.

Comment: Alright, I can only wish you good luck. All I know is that the world won't be a better place once we know why `CHECKSUM('-a') = CHECKSUM('a') = CHECKSUM('a-')` -- at best we'll be more convinced why it shouldn't be used.

Comment: Actually, all three of those`CHECKSUM()`'s show up differently when I tried them on SQL Server Express. Now, the `BINARY_CHECKSUM()` may very well have those collisions but I haven't messed with that one.

Comment: I'd be really interested to know what version of SQL Server that is and/or what default collation is used, because [that's not my experience](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ca68e0a932d02a2f2de0fecaa70a335). `BINARY_CHECKSUM` is actually the one that works differently.

Comment: Sure thing! I downloaded SQL Server Express 2017 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express . This was installed on a Windows 10 VM using all of the default settings with the exception of having it run on port 1433 as the main SQL instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent the day reverse engineering this by first dumping all results for single ASCII characters as well as pairs. This showed that each character has its own distinct "XOR code" and letters have the same one regardless of case. The algorithm was remarkably simple to figure out after that: rotate 4 bits left and xor by the code stored in a lookup table.

```js
var xorcodes = [
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
    24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
    0, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,  //  !"#$%&'
    40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,  // ()*+,-./
    132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139,  // 01234567
    140, 141, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54,  // 89:;<=>?@
    142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149,  // ABCDEFGH
    150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157,  // IJKLMNOP
    158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165,  // QRSTUVWX
    166, 167, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,  // YZ[\]^_`
    142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149,  // abcdefgh
    150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157,  // ijklmnop
    158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165,  // qrstuvwx
    166, 167, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66,  // yz{|}~
];

function rol(x, n) {
    // simulate a rotate shift left (>>> preserves the sign bit)
    return (x<<n) | (x>>>(32-n));
}

function checksum(s) {
    var checksum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        checksum = rol(checksum, 4);

        var c = s.charCodeAt(i);
        var xorcode = 0;
        if (c < xorcodes.length) {
            xorcode = xorcodes[c];
        }
        checksum ^= xorcode;
    }
    return checksum;
};
```

See https://github.com/neilodonuts/tsql-checksum-javascript for more info.

**DISCLAIMER**: I've only worked on compatibility with `VARCHAR` strings in SQL Server with collation set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. This won't work with multiple columns or integers but I'm sure the underlying algorithm uses the same codes so it wouldn't be hard to figure out. It also seems to differ from db<>fiddle possibly due to collation: https://github.com/neilodonuts/tsql-checksum-javascript/blob/master/data/dbfiddle-differences.png ... mileage may vary!

[image: CHECKSUM tests on SQL Server Express using string literals w/ hyphens]

Comment: Although `CHECKSUM` is obviously based on *something* like this, the output of T-SQL's `CHECKSUM` does not match the output of this function. Notably,`0` and `00` yield `99` and `51118860`, while this code gives `1321` and `2244`, so neither the base value nor the actual shift are correct. `CHECKSUM`'s unique and bizarre behavior of effectively ignoring hyphen characters (`-`) as if they were not in the string at all is also not preserved.

Comment: Note that `CHECKSUM` can be applied to multiple columns of different types, giving entirely different results (`CHECKSUM('0', '0') != CHECKSUM('00') != CHECKSUM(0, 0)`) but I assume that's not what you were testing.

Comment: Correct. I only tested `VARCHAR` and in those cases `CHECKSUM()` did _not_ ignore hyphens (in SQL Server Express).

Comment: Really weird and improbable! The actual algorithm for `CHECKSUM` has remained the same since it was introduced (obviously, for compatibility's sake) and it certainly does not vary across editions either. I do not have the resources to set up a completely separate VM with the download linked above. Could you add the result of `SELECT @@VERSION` of this, and also the result of `CAST('a-' AS VARBINARY(MAX))` to verify the string is what it appears to be? The results I'd expect are [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7daafe9cc408c6b76adeb786284ec524).

Comment: I've double checked the results of dbfiddle against my own local installation of SQL Server (`Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU17) (KB4515579) - 14.0.3238.1 (X64)   Sep 13 2019 15:49:57   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro for Workstations 10.0 <X64> (Build 18362: ) (Hypervisor) `), which gives the same results.

Comment: Also, what does `select compatibility_level, collation_name from sys.databases where database_id = DB_ID()` give? I don't *think* compat level or collation matter for `CHECKSUM`, but I haven't tested all of them.

Comment: Differences (I tested on both a production SQL Server and my SQL Server Express): https://github.com/neilodonuts/tsql-checksum-javascript/blob/master/data/dbfiddle-differences.png . Now both of these use `110, SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (US defaults) for compat/collate ... that's probably why you're seeing differences with the fiddle

Comment: Aha, so that explains that then. Compat level is irrelevant, the [collation is what's deciding this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b17ba829d4142e9d017be5e9347db1ff). This is unfortunate because, while `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is the default collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS` has been recommended instead (from 2012 onwards already, I believe), and moreover, the old `SQL_` collations appear to influence the results more (for example, the `CHECKSUM` result is different for `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` (case-sensitive) but not `Latin1_General_CS_AS`).

Comment: ...all this is just convincing me more that `CHECKSUM` should be avoided, but *especially* as an algorithm used to get results comparable across systems, as it's unsuitable for that purpose even across SQL Server databases with different collations!

Answer (score 0):

fyi, for those of you who are stuck in T-SQL legacy mode, here's a C# implementation that was tested and looks good for most strings/ints that I've been working with:

```
public static int[] xorcodes = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
    24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
    0, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,  //  !"#$%&'
    40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,  // ()*+,-./
    132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139,  // 01234567
    140, 141, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54,  // 89:;<=>?@
    142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149,  // ABCDEFGH
    150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157,  // IJKLMNOP
    158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165,  // QRSTUVWX
    166, 167, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,  // YZ[\]^_`
    142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149,  // abcdefgh
    150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157,  // ijklmnop
    158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165,  // qrstuvwx
    166, 167, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66,  // yz{|}~
};


public static int rol(int x, int n) {
    // simulate a rotate shift left (>>> preserves the sign bit)
    return ((int)x << n) | ((int)((uint)x >> (32 - n)));
}

public static int checksum(string s) {
    int checksum = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
        checksum = rol(checksum, 4);

        var c = ((int)s[i]);
        int xorcode = 0;
        if (c < xorcodes.Length) {
            xorcode = xorcodes[c];
        } 
        checksum ^= xorcode;
    }
    return checksum;
}
```